How is it possible to read a HDF5 dataset as a Python file-like object?
In order to hold original ambient sound file content together with meta and evaluation date, the sound data are copied as raw byte-to-byte stream (uint8 array) of the original sound files into data sets of a HDF5 file. So, every time, the original files can be reproduces completely. Of course, the data set contains not only the encoded PCM data but also the framing of the original file around these data. In my case the original files are opus-files. But it could be also mp3 or any other format. There are no HDF5 plugins for decoding. So I have to do it outside the HDF5 data access.
In order to use the data in different evaluation routines, I'm looking for a common solution to get access to the bytes in the HDF5 data set as a file object. So I could bind the dataset by pyogg.opus_file_stream.OpusFileStream(filepath) in case of opus files. Or any other library like librosa.
Frank
My solution is, to unpack the data into a temporary file and use this. But is there a possibility to interpret the HDF5 dataset as a file without any data copy?

The OpusFileStream only accepts input files as path strings and opens them themselves. I don't see how you could give any input to that library that isn't a proper file. In general, if a library accepts file objects, you can usually subclass io.RawIOBase and implement things like seeking and reading to access parts of a dataset in HDF5

@Homer512: I could see this fact also, in the mean time. The simple solution, creating an real temporary intermediate file, not a Python file-like-object, is the way to work with the opus library without any deep hack inside this library. io.RawIOBase is a file-like object of Python. Creating a file-like-object of these type seems not working with Opus. (Or, I made a mistake during test this.)

Under the hood,
Opus
is assigning
self.of = opus.op_open_file(ogg.to_char_p(path), ctypes.pointer(error))

Even without
monkey patching,
it seems like you should be able to create
f = OpusFileStream(my_example_ogg_file)
in the standard supported way, and then go assign to
f.of = ... some file-like object
corresponding to your HDF5 byte stream.
Be sure to set f.channels et al. to values
appropriate for the HDF5 audio content.

Alternatively, you might choose to subclass OpusFileStream
so you can define a suitable constructor.
And then you get to reuse the existing get_buffer() method,
plus its ..._as_array() variant.

If you implement code for HDF5 use cases, consider submitting a
PR
to the upstream maintainers.
Other Opus users may have unmet needs similar to your own.

Thanks, J_H! But this work around seems to need more steps. Any time I call a library method, I get an error like "ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 1: TypeError: expected LP_OggOpusFile instance instead of _io.BytesIO". The library accepts only a real file object, opened by opus.op_open_file(ogg.to_char_p(path), ctypes.pointer(error)) – So I will use a real temporary intermediate file.
